# dynamically load content on scroll when the user reaches the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I created a very large unordered list and I need to dynamically load content on scroll when the user reaches the bottom of the page. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll

Comment: Look up lazy loading on the interwebs...

Comment: Suggestion: just don't. Especially if you have links in the footer. This behavior is good in theory but is ridiculously annoying in practice. http://vk.com is a sad example.