# Webpage which moves to new page as we scroll down

Tags: css, scroll

I am kind of new to webdesign.  I observed that recently several companies have starterd getting websites where when we scroll down automatically it goes to the next page. For example something like http://www.extremeheadphones.com/. What is this sort of template called and are there any open source designs for it?

Comment: Like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll

Comment: That's not changing pages -- the URL stays the same. It's just one long page with various background colors/images. There's nothing stopping you from doing this yourself; just make a long page.

Comment: So you want the clicking of the arrow to change the URL as well for history purposes? Do you mean the url changes in the sense that it goes from 'example.com/#home' to 'example.com/#aboutus' and then adds the previous 'URL' to browser history?

Answer (score 1):

That's not changing pages -- the URL stays the same. It's just one long page with various background colors/images. There's nothing stopping you from doing this yourself; just make a long page

Credits: [Joe White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87399/joe-white)