# how to load more data on scroll or scrolling in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load more data while scrolling the contents. I found a solution from here:
[jQuery load more data on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll)

I want to use the jQuery Waypoint plugin. Can we load more data while scrolling, and implement in this fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/N5LZB/32/

```
var pages = [page_1, page_2, page_3, page_4, page_5];

var count=0;
$("#preRealTimeContents").html(pages[count]);

$("#realTimeContents").html(pages[count+1]);
```

Comment: They have an example referred from their documentation. Did you check that? http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/

Comment: I found that but I am not able to implement on my fiddle

Comment: here is link of waypont jquerry js http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.js

Comment: What is your main problem?

Comment: I want smooth scrolling .It mean I don't want to hit bottom of div .I want to load data while scrolling .It mean When I was in last (last div ) it load more data

Comment: I want to use visible div concept .If user in last div it append more data .

Comment: Example on starting user See Page 1 and Page 2 .But when User scroll contend in Page 2 it load page 3 and when user on page 3 it load page 4 ...so on

Comment: This can be done When I hit bottom of div , But that is not smooth scrolling .I need smoth scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var scrollFlag=true;
$('#fullContainer').scroll(function () {
    if (scrollFlag && this.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() <= 0) {
        count++;
        if (count >= pages.length) scrollFlag = false;
        $("#preRealTimeContents").append(pages[count]);
    }
});
```

[Non-circular live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/N5LZB/35/)

**Updated** load all div once on scrolling like,

```
var pages = [page_1, page_2, page_3, page_4, page_5];
var count = 0;
$("#preRealTimeContents").html(pages[count]);
var scrollFlag=true;
$('#fullContainer').scroll(function () {
    for(i=1,len=pages.length;i<len;i++,count++) {
        if (count >= len) break;
        $("#preRealTimeContents").append(pages[count]);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/N5LZB/41/)

Comment: Sorry it is not correct answer ,,It hit the bottom of dib..I need while scrolling

Comment: If you change the condition `if (scrollFlag && this.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() <= 20) {` then it will not hit the bottom See this http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/N5LZB/39/ Also if there are minor change then you should also try it.

Comment: ok First thing if user scroll fastly downword direction it load all page

Comment: can we restrict that it only load at one time

Comment: can we load  more data (one page at one time).Because When User scroll fastly it load last page

Comment: your last demo is wrong I need when user hit bottom it load one page only some time it load more pages

Comment: I applied your concept in this fiddle please check http://jsfiddle.net/N5LZB/42/ it looking nice.But When I check on Ipad and scroll to bottom fastly it load last page

Comment: it is working fine in desktop browser.Please check fiddle .It is showing page 4 and page 5.When you scroll bottom it do nothing,But when You scroll up it load page 3 and then page 2..so on.It work fine in IPAD.But Now when User scroll bottom it should load page 3 and page 4 one at one time .But when user scroll fast it state way load page 5

Comment: Please check my fiddle