# want to display ten items at a time from list in django template

Tags: jquery, python, django, cordova

I want to load the slot of 10 items each time in django.
When i click on load more button it should disply slot of next 10 items.

```
{% for book in books|slice:":10" %}
```

This is only displaying the first 10 items. But want to display all items in 10's slot. For that i dont want to use pagination.
Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll

Comment: Why not create an Ajax request instead of loading everything?

Comment: Use a paginator, along with an AJAX request to fetch 10 items at a time.

Comment: paginator is not working in phonegap android

Answer (score 0):

consider a variable in `view` such that

```
v="{}:{}".format(i,i+10)
```

increment the value according to requirement

```
{% for book in books|slice:"{{v}}" %}
```

Comment: can you give this answer in detail