# Products fade in/appear on scrolling down page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, prestashop

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? On our site we prefer not to have pagination and have all products on one page, however we have seen it done on other sites where as you scroll, the products appear into view.

This is an example of our site in a category with a lot of products: http://goo.gl/OiHIFO

If someone could help/advise or offer a link to something which will achieve this for us i'd appreciate it.

Comment: you may google for `lazy loading` :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll may provide you some help

Comment: Refer to [Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Answer (score 0):

The way you could do it is using similar methods to pagination where you load the first 50 but when you get to almost the bottom it would then make an ajax call and pull the next 50.

Those next 50 would then be appended to the results or faded in using jQuery.

Its better to load the content as you need it rather than loading everything at once but only displaying the actual product when you scroll to it