# Implement yiinfinite-scroll without database in yii1

Tags: php, yii

How to implement yiinfinite-scroll in my project. I don't have any idea about this. Can anyone help me with this.

I don't have database,contents are directly loaded from server itself.

Comment: Don't use the Yii plugin then, just use JavaScript to show more content as the user scrolls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll

Comment: I referred the site but  its not working...

Comment: Check if the user is at the [bottom of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom), if so, show more content using jQuery `show()`