# Silent load of new URL on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, loading

I've been seeing this trend of pages silently loading as you scroll. For ex:
http://www.adweek.com/brand-marketing/as-soda-consumption-declines-heres-how-coca-cola-is-reshaping-itself/

After you scroll past the article, a new article loads in and the URL changes.

Digging through the source code and can't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Use F12 tools and you can see that a lot of JavaScript code is loaded. Look also at the Network tab.

Comment: Keep your goals in mind: "For Infinite Scroll, Bounce Rate Is a Vanity Stat" http://adrianroselli.com/2015/05/for-infinite-scroll-bounce-rate-is.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, those implemntations looks for the scrooling of the user and load new contents via ajax.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
           // change url
    }
});
```

Look here: [jQuery load more data on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll)