# How to go to another page with animations when scroll the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a portfolio website for a filmmaker. 
I would like to know how to go to another page and change the URL when just scroll the window like these websites(http://taotajima.jp/, http://maxxhat.com/). Are these pages in one html document or multiple documents?
I searched and tried to solve it by myself but couldn't find the answer since I'm a junior developer. I would like to know at least what I need to learn to actually do it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silent load of new URL on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352118/silent-load-of-new-url-on-scroll)

Comment: They are in a single page, each time the website is scroll down you load in new content view a jQuery AJAX call and update the URL parameter or display new elements. They might also load a new page without refreshing also using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

A new feature offers you a way to change the URL displayed in the browser* through javascript without reloading the page. It will also create a back-button event and you even have a state object you can interact with.
 You can programmatically invoke the back-function by running:

```
window.history.back();
```

If you need to manipulate a state (instead of creating a new one) you can use:

```
window.history.replaceState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/another-new-url”);
```

Check the example here [LINK](https://www.flickr.com/photos/aknacer/3007419018/)

Full Example is Found [Here](https://computerrock.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)