# Break a long list into pages (EJS-jQuery-AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I'm working on a dashboard with **Node.js**, using `express`, however, sometimes I generate lists that are extremely long and I want to break them in pages of 20 items, people will have buttons to go to the previous/next page, but I don't know what would be the ideal way to replace the HTML from the list so it shows the 20 previous/next items (depending on which button they press).

I'm using `Bootstrap 3.3.7` and `jQuery 3.2.1`, but I can also use AJAX if needed (requesting data from a local API endpoint). And `express 4.15.3` for **Node.js**.

The data I use to generate the list is an **Array of Objects** (JSON).

Comment: Refer to this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll

Comment: If the data is presentable in table format I would use dataTables.net - it does all of this out of the box with pagination options

Comment: @ThomasK That doesn't seem to reply what I want to do. I just need to know how can I do the pagination (not infinite scroll).

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the data comes as an array of objects (JSON), not as HTML.

Comment: Have a look at dataTables, it can handle most data types

Comment: Oh, I did but didn't see the js_array page. I'll take a look in that. Does it support custom HTML inside the rows?

Comment: Regardless of that, that gave me an idea I can do with jQuery, I'll reply to this question once I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought, I download the array of objects and assign it to an array, then, use `jQuery.html()`, `jQuery.map()` and `Array.slice()` to create the page with 'x' amount of items. When clicking on one of both buttons, it'll change the page and re-slice the array to show the previous/next page.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <nav aria-label="guildPager">
            <ul class="pager">
                <li id="previousPage" class="previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span></li>
                <li id="nextPage" class="next"><span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="guildList"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var arr = [{...}, {...}, ..., {...}];
    var page = 0;
    var amount = 20;
    var pages = Math.ceil(arr.length / amount);

    function pagify() {
        if (page === 0 && !$("#previousPage").hasClass("disabled")) $("#previousPage").addClass("disabled");
        else if ($("#previousPage").hasClass("disabled")) $("#previousPage").removeClass("disabled");

        if (page === pages - 1 && !$("#nextPage").hasClass("disabled")) $("#nextPage").addClass("disabled");
        else if ($("#nextPage").hasClass("disabled")) $("#nextPage").removeClass("disabled");

        $("#guildList").html($.map(arr.slice(page * amount, (page * amount) + amount), (a) => {
            return `<h4>${a.name}<small> ${a.users} members.</small></h4><hr></hr><br />`;
        }));
    }
    pagify();

    $("#nextPage").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) return;
        page++;
        pagify();
    });
    $("#previousPage").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) return;
        page--;
        pagify();
    });
</script>
```