# Infinite rows when scrolling in a html table

Tags: html, dynamic, html-table, infinite-scroll

I would like to create a smart or dynamic table in HTML which has infinite rows for stock columns, I mean, where it shows by default 30 rows for example, but when you scroll it creates and shows another 30 infinitely.

Other good option would be create the amount of rows specified in a textfield and clicking a button.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll

Comment: removed php tag and referenced html instead