# How do you make an image slide into the screen and slide off during a certain phase of the website scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen many websites introduce a nice feature when you're scrolling down the website and suddenly during a certain part of the website scroll, lets say during 40% to 70% of the screen full page an image will appear from either left or right side and sit in the middle of the screen until the user will scroll up/down far enough to which the image will slide outwards.

How could I implement such a feature?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @DacreDenny Despite having an understanding of HTML/CSS/JS, I have no idea how I could implement such a feature and so far have not done anythin :/.

Comment: Ok - you'll usually want to provide something to give your question a little more traction with the community, be that some HTML/CSS relevant to your required page structure, or a bit of javascript to show that you've given this some thought.

Comment: You could do it, by define an interval (min-height and max-height) which will have to listen the scroll event, and slide in or off the image you want in that interval of heights. Sounds a very interesting challenge for learning. But there must be a library to do that.

Comment: @Yoarthur I've read a bit about KeyFrames and web-kit for animating the image to appear from left->right. However I cannot think of a way to make this occur during a certain level of scrolling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery load more data on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

Well, here are some pointers:

- detect and handle the scroll event: `window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) { ... });`
- get current scroll position: `window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop` (you will probably compare it with another value):

  ```
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

        var position = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if(position > ...)
            ...
        ...
    });
  ```
- may be you want to use a library, look for "scroll animation (js, library)", there are [many](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/scrolling-effects-js-libraries/)

Comment: or use body instead of window