# PHP - Loop through array and print out value only if it changes between iteration

Tags: php, arrays

Apologies if this has been asked but I can't find a solution that meets my needs.

I have an array in a PHP 7 application as follows:

```
$data = [
    0 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'Europe',
        'groups_label' => 'G1',
        'filters_label' => 'FF1'
    ],
    1 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'Europe',
        'groups_label' => 'G1',
        'filters_label' => 'FF900'
    ],
    2 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'Europe',
        'groups_label' => 'G1',
        'filters_label' => 'FF324234'
    ],
    3 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'Europe',
        'groups_label' => 'G2',
        'filters_label' => 'FF23942'
    ],
    4 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'America',
        'groups_label' => 'G29',
        'filters_label' => 'FF3242'
    ],
    5 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'America',
        'groups_label' => 'G29',
        'filters_label' => 'FF78978'
    ],
    6 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'America',
        'groups_label' => 'G29',
        'filters_label' => 'FF48395043'
    ],
    7 => [
        'regulations_label' => 'Asia',
        'groups_label' => 'G2000',
        'filters_label' => 'FF7'
    ],
    // ...
];
```

The output I want to achieve is like this:

```
Europe
    - G1
        -- FF1
        -- FF900
    - G2
        -- FF23942

America
    - G29
        -- FF3242
        -- FF48395043

Asia
    - G2000
        -- FF7
```

Essentially all it's doing is outputting the array in a structured format such that it shows the `regulations_label` followed by any corresponding `groups_label` and then any `filters_label`.

It's simple enough to loop through the entire array, e.g.

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
    echo $d['regulations_label'] . "\n";
    echo ' - ' . $d['groups_label'] . "\n";
    echo ' -- ' . $d['filters_label'] . "\n";
}
```

However this introduces "duplicate" headings for `regulations_label` and `groups_label` because it's printing every single key. But I don't see how I can check if this has changed during the `foreach` statement because `$d` is always the current element.

I was attempting to do a check based on the previous array key:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
   if ($data[$key-1]['regulations_label'] !== $d['regulations_label']) {
       echo $d['regulations_label'] . "\n";
       echo "-" . $d['groups_label'] . "\n";
   }
}
```

The trouble is that this then just prints 1 `groups_label` so I'd end up with - for example:

```
Europe
- G1
America
...
```

It wouldn't get as far as "G2".

I can't help but think I'm going about this in a bizarre way. Can anyone advise a better solution?

*Background info: The data I receive in `$data` isn't something I can modify because that format is required for the use case which is a feature in an application like this: [jQuery load more data on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `foreach` and group by using `regulations_label` and `groups_label`

```
$group = [];
foreach($data as $v){
  $group[$v['regulations_label']][$v['groups_label']][] = $v['filters_label'];
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/6aNmX)

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case you just need to add some `if` statements as you'd started to do, but you also have to make sure they only stop the relevant bit from printing - your version was suppressing the whole output, instead of just the top-level label:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $d) {
   if ($key > 0) {
       if ($data[$key-1]['regulations_label'] !== $d['regulations_label']) {
           echo $d['regulations_label'] . "\n";   

       }
       if ($data[$key-1]['groups_label'] !== $d['groups_label']) {
           echo "-" . $d['groups_label'] . "\n";
       }
   }
   else
   {
       //special case to deal with first row where $key-1 doesn't exist
       echo $d['regulations_label'] . "\n";   
       echo "-" . $d['groups_label'] . "\n";
   }
   echo ' -- ' . $d['filters_label'] . "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ihYVj

Comment: This is a good solution as it causes fewer issues than the accepted answer with the memory overhead from the `$group` array. It's giving a `Notice: Undefined offset: -1 ` error though.

Comment: @Andy sorry about that... see updated demo and code sample above. It's just an issue with the first row, because obviously when $key is 0, there's no array index at $key-1!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remember what you last processed and then adda couple of IF's

```
$data = [
    0 => ['regulations_label' => 'Europe','groups_label' => 'G1','filters_label' => 'FF1'],
    1 => ['regulations_label' => 'Europe','groups_label' => 'G1','filters_label' => 'FF900'],
    2 => ['regulations_label' => 'Europe','groups_label' => 'G1','filters_label' => 'FF324234'],
    3 => ['regulations_label' => 'Europe','groups_label' => 'G2','filters_label' => 'FF23942'],
    4 => ['regulations_label' => 'America','groups_label' => 'G29','filters_label' => 'FF3242'],
    5 => ['regulations_label' => 'America','groups_label' => 'G29','filters_label' => 'FF78978'],
    6 => ['regulations_label' => 'America','groups_label' => 'G29','filters_label' => 'FF48395043'],
    7 => ['regulations_label' => 'Asia','groups_label' => 'G2000','filters_label' => 'FF7']
];

$last_reg = NULL;
$last_grp = NULL;

foreach ($data as $reg) {

    if ( $last_reg != $reg['regulations_label']) {
        echo $reg['regulations_label'] . "\n";
        $last_reg = $reg['regulations_label'];
        $last_grp = NULL;
        $last_filter = NULL;
    }
    if ( $last_grp != $reg['groups_label']) {
        echo "\t - " . $reg['groups_label'] . "\n";
        $last_grp = $reg['groups_label'];
    }
    echo "\t\t - " . $reg['filters_label'] . "\n";
}
```

RESULT:

```
Europe
     - G1
         - FF1
         - FF900
         - FF324234
     - G2
         - FF23942
America
     - G29
         - FF3242
         - FF78978
         - FF48395043
Asia
     - G2000
         - FF7
```