# jQUery know when we reach end of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load ajax data when I reach the end of a particular div.

I use now :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (! loadingAjax) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($element.offset().top + $element.outerHeight() - 500)) {
            from++;
            loadingAjax = true;
            loadMyData(from);
        }
    }
});
```

It seems a little random when I show console for example, or on smartphone.

What is the best way to detect user is reaching end of a div ($element here) ? With an offset of 50px for example before the end ?

Comment: I believe that stackoverflow is full of similar questions... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll

Comment: This question (like a lot of others) don't answer my question. Read comments of accepted answer, and you will see the original question is not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the solution and you will be console logged in the last div.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.posts').offset().top + 
  $('.posts').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
      console.log('End Div');
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, the window.innerHeight seems to make it more accurate. Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it to be accurate and serves your purpose.