# How to load div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

How to load `div` and it's child elements when scroll event occurred with jquery?

For example, i just want to load this div and content inside this `div` only when user scroll

```
<div id="loadonscroll">
  //some images and scripts inside this div need to be load on scroll

</div>
```

Comment: This question already has good tutorials/answers available, while posting a question you should also tell us what you tried and where you got stuck. Here's a working fiddle (not mine, plenty of examples out there). http://jsfiddle.net/brynner/QDttv/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery load more data on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll)

Comment: Can you please code the above example?

Answer (score 3):

this works for me. When you scroll data will append on DIV TAG. and it should be displayed after Scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           // ajax call and append data on DIV 
           $("#loadonscroll").html(ajaxData);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
//Scroll to buttom


$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        var data = html code
 $("#loadonscroll").html(data);
   }
});

// near bottom!

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
       var data = html code
 $("#loadonscroll").html(data);
   }
});
```