# How to make Jquery datatable load more data on page scroll

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using ASP.NET MVC and initially the HTML table data is loaded from the server (loop data using razor).

In `document.Ready()` I am applying jQuery datatable on the HTML table.
All data is returned from the server. I just need to show it 10 rows every page scroll.

How to make the datatable load more data on page scroll?

```
var table = $('#reports_total_spend_table').DataTable({
           "order": [[1, 'asc']],
           paging: false,
           searching: false,
           info: false,
           fixedHeader: true,
           scrollY: "450px",
           scrollX: true,
           scrollCollapse: true
       });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery load more data on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll)

Comment: The data is not big. so i showed first 10 rows and hided the other rows. then i started showing 10 rows each page scroll.   $(window).on("scroll", function () 
       {          
           if ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight > $(document).height() - 50)
           {             
               $("tbody tr.main:hidden:lt(10)").removeClass('hidden');               
            }
       });