# Load more posts in a container on scroll with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, scroll

I am trying to create a nice load more posts feature when scrolling down the page in a div container and when you reach to the end of the container you see more posts. What i tried so far is working but is buggy when i scroll quite fast as it send more ajax requests then needed and is loading duplicated data.

```
 <!-- HTML Structure -->
 <header style="position:fixed"></header> 
 <section class="page-banner" style="height: 420px;"></section>
 <section class="projects-general">
    <div class="projects-wrapper">
       <div class="projects-list-wrap"></div>
    </div>
 </section>
 <section class="contact-intro"></section>  
 <footer></footer> 
 <!-- HTML Structure -->
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pjCount = $('.pj-col').length;
    var totalPj = $('#pj-numb').val();
    if (pjCount >= totalPj){
        return false;
    }else{
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.projects-list-wrap').offset().top + $('.projects-list-wrap').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight + $('header').outerHeight()) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxURL,
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.projects-wrapper').append("<div class='pj-loader'></div>");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('.pj-loader').remove();
                },
                data:{
                    action: "pj_load_more",
                    pjCount:pjCount
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('.projects-list-wrap').append(data);
                },
                error: function(err){
                    //console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas why it is ok when you try to scroll slowly but when like scrolling fast its creating that buggy effect of duplicating posts.
Many thanks

Comment: Take the AJAX call out and write the values in the `if` condition to the console. Then you can see why the state does/does not hit

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, am trying to check that.

Comment: You might also consider [debouncing the event handler](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to limit how often it fires. It may help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Can you throw your PHP in to the question as well.

Comment: @showdev thanks a lot for the article, i tried but still issue still persist as seems the way am detecting if user reached to position where posts can be loaded has some sort of bug in calculation :(

Comment: @TonyDjukic php works all good, loads more posts properly, issue is all comign from js thats why posted only js.

Comment: It's difficult to tell how the scroll position is calculated without seeing your HTML structure (e.g. the `.projects-list-wrap` and `header` elements).

Comment: @showdev yes for sure, my bad. I updated the question, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: I really am tempted to close that with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll) as a duplicate... Please have a look at the condition used there and if it works for you.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette no this is not really in my case, i tried it many times :(

Comment: You tried `$(document).height() - $(window).height()`? That seems more clear and simple to me. Maybe something else is going wrong that isn't reproducible from the code you've shown here. Using your calculation, it doesn't seem that you need to add the header height. Here is a [demonstration of both calculations](https://jsfiddle.net/b02xt9Lf/1/).

Comment: I made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/RwowJNO) in order to test your condition with the little code you provided. I "feaked" some ajax response... Please edit your question with what is missing... Because that "attempt to reproduce" seems to demonstrate your code is working.

Comment: Incidentally, `<section class="page-banner" height: 420px;>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: I tried $(document).height() - $(window).height() and a lot more tweaks but bug keeps on going. Actually it's because am trying to detect when user scrolls to bottom part of the container so i load more projects and when i do fast scroll seems the end of container is being calculated wrongly and as ajax is in scroll event is being fired multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ajax call takes time (opposed to my [attempt to reproduce](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/RwowJNO?editors=1011)) and the `scroll` event is firing like a machinegun...

The same ajax request could be triggered more than once.

To avoid that, use a flag `ajax_request_sent` like so:

```
// A flag to know if a request is sent and the response is not yet received
let ajax_request_sent = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var pjCount = $('.pj-col').length;
  var totalPj = $('#pj-numb').val();
  if (pjCount >= totalPj) {
    return false;
  } else {

    // Use the flag in the condition (so if sent and not yet received == false)
    if (!ajax_request_sent && $(window).scrollTop() >= $('.projects-list-wrap').offset().top + $('.projects-list-wrap').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight + $('header').outerHeight()) {

      // Set the flag to prevent any concurring request
      ajax_request_sent = true
    
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('.projects-wrapper').append("<div class='pj-loader'></div>");
        },
        complete: function() {
          $('.pj-loader').remove();
        },
        data: {
          action: "pj_load_more",
          pjCount: pjCount
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.projects-list-wrap').append(data);
          
          // Unset the flag
          ajax_request_sent = false;
        },
        error: function(err) {
          //console.log(err);
        }
      });
      
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yaaaay, you saved my day @Louys Patrice Bessette. Issue was exactly the delay time for ajax and really very quick scroll event firing. Your solution worked out perfectly, thanks a million