# jQuery .load to bring data is working only the first time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load more data from a database with a jQuery `.load`, and it works perfectly, but after the first load, it ist'n bringing more data.

Also, for bringing the first content, which is brought on the first page load, i use a PHP `foreach()` loop, like this as a basic example:

```
<div class="grid-products">
    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
        <div class="grid-product">
          <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I am trying to load more data from my database on scroll, so the user don't have to click on a button. I am loading information from my database based on the method of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll) question, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        //do an ajax call
    }
});
```

But as I don't know how to do the ajax call mentioned on the answer above I found, I decided to use a jquery `.load` passing also some `POST` method variables, which in this case would be `productNewCount`. First I set its value to 6, and when user reaches bottom of page, we sum plus six to its value, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var productCount = 6;

    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        productCount = productCount + 6;

        $(".grid-products").load("load-products.php", {
            productNewCount: productCount
        });
    }
});
```

This works great on first load, and so when this is executed, it loads on the `<div class="grid-products">` the `load-products.php` file. Here, the variable `$connection` is calling my function to connect to the database, don't give too much importance to it.

This is `load-products.php`:

```
<?php 

$connection = connect();

$product_new_count = $_POST['productNewCount'];

$sentence = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM all_products ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $product_new_count
");
$sentence->execute();

$products = $sentence;

?>

<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
    <div class="grid-product">
        <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the sentence, we are calling to bring all the rows from the `all_products` table ordered through its `date` column, and limiting to bring only the rows `product_new_count` says, which its value is the `productCount` JS variable we brought on the main file, before its load.

I made sure there are still rows available to bring, so the reason why other rows arent being shown after first load isn't because there are no rows left. Also, terminal isnt showing any errors or warnings and there is also still available space to make scroll so the function can be called.

Can I bring more data through this `.load` method or should I use the AJAX call mentioned on the answer I found? If so how?

Comment: Are you trying to add to existing? If so `load()` won't work since it replaces everything inside `$(".grid-products")` each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you scroll `productCount`  is set to 6, hence all your load request will be the same.
You can define `productCount` outside the event handler to increase the number of elements loaded each time.

```
var productCount = 6;
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        productCount = productCount + 6;

        $(".grid-products").load("load-products.php", {
            productNewCount: productCount
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add to the existing content (not replace all of it) use `$.post` instead of `load()` and append the results.

`load()` replaces whatever is already existing inside the matching selector

```
$.post("load-products.php", {productNewCount: productCount}, function(html){
    $(".grid-products").append(html)
})
```